# Median of a Trapezoid

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I am working on a calculator with my high school students.  We are not using a library yet so we are doing all the calculations the long way.  We are using user input numbers with int and input values. We have a menu at the top with all of functions below. We aren't at floats yet but if we need to use them we can, I just need to be able to explain to them why, when, and how to use a float. So my student came up with a formula and we don't know what is the issue.

```
'''
#Variables#
things = ['Area of a Square', 'Area of a Rectangle', 'Weight of an Object','Speed of an Object','Density of an Object', 'Velocity of an Object', 'Mass of an Object','Area of a Triangle','Median of a Trapezoid', 'Quit']
'''
'''
#Function#
'''
# printMenu() displays the menu
def printMenu ():
    c = 1
    for i in things:
        print ('%i:\t%s' % (c, i))
        c = c + 1
'''
-------

So here is the problem that is kicking our butts:
'''
#Calculates Median of a Trapezoid
def medianTrap ():
   base3 = input ('Enter  first base:  ')
   base4 = input ('Enter second base:  ')
   medianTrap = ((int base3 + int base4/ 2))
   print ('The Median of an Trapezoid is:  %i' % (medianTrap))
   print()
```

'''
HELP!!!!

Comment: It's helpful to post the exact error message that you get when running your code as well as to make sure that we can reproduce the error by copy-pasting and running the snippet you include. E.g. if you use `input` in your real code, you can post an example where you just set the variable equal to a reasonable input value, such as `base3 = 10` instead of `base3 = input()`, so that we know we're testing the same input value as you used (though here any value would lead to the same error).

Comment: Hi Nathan. Sorry about that. I need to explain why we used base3 = input(). We are setting up the calculator to receive a user generated number. So the variable could be any number of that makes sense. The students stated that often times when doing their homework they might be given different numbers from the teacher (I guess to keep them from cheating). 

This was my first post here so I wasn’t sure of what exactly to post. I will make sure to follow your advice for future questions. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line:

```
medianTrap = ((int base3 + int base4/ 2))
```

That's not Python syntax, int is a function a thus you gotta wrap the argument into parentheses:

```
medianTrap = ((int(base3) + int(base4)/ 2))
```

Good luck with your students !

Comment: You also do not need the double parenthesis you could just do `int(base3) + int(base4)/ 2`. And you can apply the int during the input (`base3 = int(input ('Enter  first base:  '))`) for clarity then use just `base3 + base4/ 2`